# I get this same error everytime I try to run rake db:migrate on a cloned project from Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

Everything I clone a project on Github and then run `rake db:migrate`, I get this error (project name is mini_fb_demo):

```
$ git clone http://github.com/appoxy/mini_fb_demo.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/ben/rails_projects/mini_fb_demo/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 102, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (91/91), done.
remote: Total 102 (delta 24), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (102/102), 77.94 KiB | 47 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (24/24), done.
$ cd mini_fb_demo/
$ ls
README.markdown Rakefile    app     config      db      doc     public      script      test
$ rake db:migrate
(in /Users/ben/rails_projects/mini_fb_demo)
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - /Users/ben/.minifb-demo-config.yml
```

What is causing this? I Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the wiki for the project [here](http://github.com/appoxy/mini_fb_demo/blame/master/README.markdown). You need to create the minifb-demo-config.yml file as specified there.